# Angular 8: How to style the layout of a component itself (e.g., from a parent?)

Tags: css, angular, angular8

My Angular 8 app has a simple structure:

app.component.html:

```
<app-main-nav></app-main-nav>
<div id="main-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I would like the `<app-main-nav>` (which is like a conventional "left nav") to be 160px wide, and 100% of the viewport tall. The `<div id="main-container">` should fill the rest of rest of the screen.

Ordinarily, I would make the entire page (`body`?) a flex container, and set the `flex` properties on the `<app-main-nav>` and `<div id="main-container">` elements.

But, how to do I set the css properties of the `<app-main-nav>` component? How to I select it in `app.component.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in your `app.component.css` something like:

```
app-main-nav {
/*your css rules */
}
```

you could also select the component by id or class. Be aware that Angular components are `inline` by default so you may have to set it's `display` property to `block` or something like that.